# Apache Camel corrupted http response

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Camel to `route http requests`. A client reaches my Camel router at a `servlet` endpoint providing the information required to route the request, then I lookup into the database to resolve the endpoint. The requests are routed correctly but the response I get seems to be corrupted (I'm making the call from a Rest client), here the corrupted response:

[image]

If I call the **destination** endpoint without passing from camel it returns the right response:

[image]

I also checked that the response leaves the **destination** endpoint not corrupted.

Here my Camel `configuration classes`:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class CamelStartupBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes(new CamelRouteConfiguration());
        camelContext.start();
    }

    static class CamelRouteConfiguration extends RouteBuilder {

        @Override
        public void configure() {
            from("servlet:callService?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                    .routeId("callService")
                    .recipientList(method(CallServiceConfiguration.class, "resolveServiceRoute"));
        }

    }

    static class CallServiceConfiguration {

        public String resolveServiceRoute(Exchange exchange) {
            String route;
            // lookup the database to find a route ...
            route = "http://demo.apps.closhlab.osh.local/rest/DemoService?bridgeEndpoint=true";
            return route;
        }

    }

}
```

I'm using `Camel 3.9.0` and my app is deployed on the Docker image `jboss/wildfly:15.0.0.Final`.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Camel 3.11.0 solved the issue.